# Calculate the return rate from the initial and final fund value

Tags: money-market

I'm trying to calculate the compound return rate from multiple variables: the initial fund, the final fund and the period.

Suppose I have `$10000` right now, if I can do a compound return rate at 10%, 10 years from now it would become `$10000 * (1.1 ^ 10) = $25937`.

Now If I want the revenue to be $30000 after 10 years, how should I calculate the compound return rate?

Comment: @keshlam The question you mentioned above is completely unrelated to my question. My question is a math problem, not a general one. Please remove your close request and do not mislead other people, thanks.

Comment: Apologies, pointed to the wrong prior, but this HAS been answered before. However, it's also trivial to explain, so I'll answer it again.

Comment: @keshlam no problem, you just gave a great answer to me, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This IS a question that has been asked and answered many times before -- and in fact the answer can be derived directly from your example by straight algebra.

```
10000*(x^10)=30000, solve for x.
x^10=3
x=3^(1/10)
x=1.116, rounded off
Return of 11.6%
```

Extra credit: If you have some calculus, compute the rate if compounded continuously, then compute what the growth would be after some completely arbitrary length of time.